# Export bookmarks via Chrome command line?

Tags: google-chrome, browser, bookmarks

I'm not sure if there's a good/simple way to do what I want to do. What I'm looking for is export *browser* bookmarks in Google Chrome, via a terminal command. I'm currently looking for a way to export in the Netscape HTML bookmarks file format, but if there's a way that sync plugins do it, that I can use or emulate from the command line, that works too -- looking for something I can automate.

I know headless Chrome is making head way in its development, so that might be an option. Any concrete answers appreciated!